# Google Analytics on Demo Site

Tags: google-analytics

Will adding the UA code of the live site to a revision site affect anything adversely? They are, technically, two different sites with different metrics. I don't want to lose the old data when I initiate the new site, of course. I would also like to work on setting up the new analytics page while the revision site is in development.

Does anyone have any good workflows on setting up a revision site without losing old site data?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow but why add the Google Analytics to the demo site? Can't you just leave the Analytics tracking off the demo site and then when your new site goes live just use the same tracking code?

Comment: Geoff,

I wanted to make sure that things were working on the demo site. Google Analytics was going through a weird transition phase there for a moment. I wanted to make sure the new Universal Analytics was working. 

I don't know if you know, but Jetpack plugin on Wordpress sites wouldn't work on local sites. It had to be on a live server. I suspected something like that was going on with GA. 

It turned out that that was not the case. Thank you for you comment anyway.

Comment: Don't forget to approve an answer if you like it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the Google Analytics code while working on the revision site or it will mess up with the old site data.

If you plan to use the same URL for both site, then you will have to backup the data for the old site one way or another, then set the GA on the revision site, while removing it from the old site at the same time, when the revision site goes live.

If you use different URLs, set the new GA code on the revised site when it is ready (i.e., going live).

Answer (score 0):

Look into using filters (under "admin").

You can filter it so that data obtained from your demo site does not appear in your view.

It is probably more logical to work the other way around and filter it so that **only** hits to your live site count, as there are other potential mistakes if you allow your GA code to work anywhere on the web. For example, scraper sites may add it to their version of the page.